# Data recovery after interrupted partitioning

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hard-drive, partition

My MacBook Pro was working fine until my friend stopped the Disk Utility from partitioning and force quit the application. Ever since it seems that the problem has grown larger and larger as I used it.

Now it boots until the half of the loading bar, stays there, and shuts down after an hour or so. I tried looking at what was happening by doing a Verbose Boot and it was fine until it said it was repairing the disk and said it failed. I tried Command-R, it also said the disk could not be repaired, I tried the command-R boot again, now it says that it couldn't connect to the Apple support and stops.

Any suggestions on booting/retrieving the data? Should I make a bootable external drive for my laptop? If so, how?

Comment: Did you try cmd+R and install OS X onto an external disk?

Comment: Can you try cmd+R with a network cable attached?

Comment: It got suck on the network part(?). I'll try it with a network cable attached.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an installable USB drive which you can boot from, follow these steps carefully to achieve that:

1. Download the Mac OS (Yosemite) from the App Store
2. Format a USB in Disk Utility and name it Untitled (very Important) You should format your USB to Mac OS X Extended (Journaled)
3. Launch Terminal and execute this command:

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app —nointeraction
   ```